# Eigen cannot access typedef unary_evaluator inside sparse matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am using Eigen v3.3.90

```
//Core/macros.h
#define EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION 3
#define EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION 3
#define EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION 90
```

and im attempting to do some sparse matrix calculations but I am getting a compile error:

> Error C2248   'Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator::InnerIterator::Scalar': cannot access private typedef declared in class 'Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator::InnerIterator'  omitted_bin d:\workspace\repositories\omitted\libigl\external\nanogui\ext\eigen\eigen\src\SparseCore\SparseDiagonalProduct.h    75

Here is the code snippet to reproduce this error:

```
    Eigen::MatrixXd a(3, 3);
    a << 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1;

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> b(3, 3);

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> result = b.cast<double>() * a.colwise().sum().asDiagonal();
```

I am trying to reproduce a repository which is attempting to the this above computation. I think this might be a case of an Eigen version mismatch as the original author may have written the code snippet using a much earlier version of Eigen.
Another code snippet which may support this is as follows:

```
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> a;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> b;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> c;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> result = b.transpose() * a * c;
```

The above snippet will result in a compile error:

> Error C2923   'Eigen::SparseMatrix': '_Scalar' is not a valid template
>   type argument for parameter '_Scalar' (compiling source file
>   D:\Workspace\Repositories\omitted\src\ApplicationPipeline.cpp)    omitted_bin d:\workspace\repositories\omitted\libigl\external\nanogui\ext\eigen\eigen\src\SparseCore\SparseUtil.h   102

I fixed the above by explicitly adding the cast:

```
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> result = b.transpose() * a.cast<int>() * c;
```

However I would like to either find the version of Eigen which allowed implicit type casting for matrices or a proper conversion behavior which replicates the Eigen version which allowed this.

Comment: Your first snippet compiles fine with 3.3.4 and the current head version (3.3.90 is any development version after 3.3.0 and before a future 3.4.-alpha/beta version): https://godbolt.org/z/gHkHgl. Your second snippet intentionally does not compile. If you had a version where this compiles, then it had a bug (or was manually changed).

Comment: @chtz thanks. I found that 3.2.10 compiles for both of my snippets.

Comment: 3.2.x is not supported anymore. I strongly advise against using that. Being able to multiply mixed types is not intended behavior.

Comment: Noted. It seems that 3.2.x is provisioned by libigl. I will try to make an issue with the devs. Thank you for the advice.